# why does Conv1D outputs dimensionality problem?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have an array of ~ 2000 spectra composed of 2000 samples. (2000X2000 array).

I am experiencing an issue with a simple network:

```
def create_model_LCNN(vec_size):
        model = models.Sequential()
        model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size =10, input_shape=(vec_size, 1)))
 
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

history = model.fit(X_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=30,
          batch_size=64,
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])
```

I get in response the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (64, 2924)

I have seen multiple questions similar to this that basically say change the dim of the input.

Why is it expecting a 3-dim array? How does the parameter timestep come into account? Does it seek a sequence (another term I saw frequently)? Sequence of what?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation at [Conv1D](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/):

> This layer creates a convolution kernel that is convolved with the layer input over a single spatial (or temporal) dimension to produce a tensor of outputs.

This means that if your elements are simply scalars (not vectors, which is the general case, which covers the case for scalars as well - length 1), you should expand the last dimension of your input array:

```
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, 2)
```

This results in an array of shape `(cca 2000, 2924, 1)`, which is valid for the `Conv1D` layer operation. Your elements (which you've got `cca 2000` of), will be taken as vectors (rank 1 tensors) and convolved independently using `64` trained kernels of shape `(10, 1)`.

Comment: First, thanks for you reply.
Second, I am still missing something in my understanding:
Suppose I have a matrix of 5 by 5. 5 registries with 5 samples each.
the input layer receives a 5X1 vector and then the conv1D (lets say it is of size 3) should work, per vector on samples 1,2,3 - 2,3,4 - 3,4,5 shouldnt it?

Why should I expand my vector?

Thanks

Comment: @KOmer Yes, your intuition is good. Somewhat. What you say is true, except for the fact that `Conv1D`, the keras-python-tf object, is well-prepared to handle not only your case, where the vectors are `5x1` (and they are actually vectors), but the `Conv1D` layer is ready to handle the case where those inputs are matrices, such as `5x3`, which makes the convolutional filters/kernels matrices as well. The reason, I think, is simply: "What if someone wants to apply 1D convolution to matrices?" That's why you must expand your vectors - the operation is identical to what you want to happen.